# How to get sub document only in mongoose?

Tags: json, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to extract only sub document from an array has the following schema :

```
const UserSchema = Schema({
name: {
    type: String
},library:[{
    story:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'Story'}
}],
});
```

i tried to use :

```
module.exports.getUserStories = function(userId, callback){
    User.findOne({_id: userId },callback)
    .select('library.story')
};
```

and it gives this result :

```
    {
  "_id": "5949615072e15d2b34fa8f9d",
  "library": [
    {
      "story": "592ae46cf2a0ba2b208cb092"
    },
    {
      "story": "592ae608df26d80790092fe9"
    },
    {
      "story": "592ae46cf2a0ba2b208cb092"
    }
  ]
}
```

but what i'm expecting to get is only this :

```
[
  {
    "story": "592ae46cf2a0ba2b208cb092"
  },
  {
    "story": "592ae608df26d80790092fe9"
  },
  {
    "story": "592ae46cf2a0ba2b208cb092"
  }
]
```

I already tried to use double selection like :

```
module.exports.getUserStories = function(userId, callback){
    User.findOne({_id: userId },callback)
    .select('library.story')
    .select('story')
};
```

But is gives the same result

Comment: even if i called  .populate() i'm still getting library on the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one :

```
module.exports.getUserStories = function(userId, callback){
    User.find({_id: userId },{'library.story'}).then(function(user){
        if(user){
            callback(user.library);
        }});
};
```

Docs [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

Answer (score 2):

This output is expected to return by "select" but simply you can prepare the returned data to be as you need as following:

```
User.findOne({_id: userId }).select('library').then(function(result){
  if(result){
    //If there is returned item
    var stories = result.library;
    //Continue ...
  }

},function(error){
  //Error handling
})
```

Comment: It seems correct, but i'm getting undefined on result.library when i tried to console.log() it

Comment: it should work,, it seems there is something wrong in your code send it to me